# Using git check-mailmap correctly

Tags: git

#### Context

There is a `.mailmap` file at the root of the project in question. It consists of entries such as these:

```
Some User <some.user@company.com> <someuser@private.com>
Some User <some.user@company.com> <dev5@company.com>
Another User <another.user@company.com> <another.user@private.com>
...
```

I found documentation on retrieving canonical contact data for any given user using `git check-mailmap`:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-mailmap

#### Question

Simple question, to which I did not find a concise answer - how does one use the command correctly?

Documentation provides syntax as follows:

```
git check-mailmap [<options>] <contact>
```

However entering *e.g.* any the following

```
git check-mailmap some.user@company.com
git check-mailmap Some User
git check-mailmap --std
```

yields no result other than

```
fatal: unable to parse contact ...
```

In addition I entered `git check-mailmap --help` to look for additional info, but it seems to me like the provided HTML is equivalent to the page I linked earlier.

So how is `git check-mailmap` being used properly?

Comment: From the linked docs: "For each “Name <user@host>” or “<user@host>…” Here `<>` are used literally. It's not a substitution, it's `Name <email>` format.

Comment: @phd Your comment helped, however I am still not completely clear on command usage. *E.g.* when entering `git check-mailmap "<someuser@private.com>"` I am being merely returned `<someuser@private.com>`, rather than `<some.user@company.com>`which I expect to be canonical. This is also true for any string entered in `"<...>"`, I am just being returned that string, even if it is not present in the `.mailmap`.

Comment: For this [`.mailmap`](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/blob/master/.mailmap) (full disclosure: I was a contributor and now I'm the developer): `git check-mailmap 'echuck'` returns *fatal: unable to parse contact: echuck*; `git check-mailmap '<echuck>'` -> *<echuck>*; `git check-mailmap 'echuck <echuck>'` -> *Chuck Esterbrook <echuck@mindspring.com>*. So it seems that how it works: it requires full `Name <email>` and only accepts bare `<email>` if there is no `Name` for the corresponding email.

Comment: I was able to confirm your statements, thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An anwer was found thanks to @phd. See comment section under opening post for details given.

The syntax I was using to call `git check-mailmap` is incorrect:

```
git check-mailmap some.user@company.com
git check-mailmap Some User
git check-mailmap --std
```

Instead, in order to retrieve a canonical alias, both a **username** and a corresponding **address** need to be provided.

In the example given a valid call may look like this:

```
git check-mailmap 'Some User <someuser@private.com>'
```

and should yield:

```
Some User <some.user@company.com>
```

A handy way to check `.mailmap` validity is usage of `git shortlog -se`.